# Dynamically assign with jquery css top and left for an image map?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an image map that has a function return text from the alt attribute. At the moment the pop is a css layer called overlay that is assigned top and left coordinates, so that the popup no matter where on the image map will always be in the same position, however I'm wondering if there is a way to assign the top and left such that it is closest to the image map being hover on?

It looks like this, notice that the popup is always on the left corner.
[image]

Here  is the code I adapter from another jfiddle.

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
    <style id="compiled-css" type="text/css">
    #map {
        position: relative;
    }
    #overlay {
        position: absolute;
        background: #000;
        color: #fff;
        top: 50px;
        left: 50px;
    
        width: 100px;
    
    }
      </style>
    <div id="map">
        <div id="overlay"></div>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/f9HmUmf.jpg" alt="test" usemap="#g1">
    </div>
    
    <map name="g1">
      <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,100,100" alt="one" href="http://www.one.com">
      <area shape="rect" coords="100,0,200,100" alt="two" href="http://www.two.com">
      <area shape="rect" coords="200,0,300,100" alt="three" href="http://www.three.com">
      <area shape="rect" coords="300,0,400,100" alt="4" href="http://www.four.com">
      <area shape="rect" coords="400,0,500,100" alt="5" href="http://www.five.com">
      
      <area shape="rect" coords="0,100,100,200" alt="1b" href="http://www.onebottom.com">
      <area shape="rect" coords="100,100,200,200" alt="2b" href="http://www.twobottom.com">
      <area shape="rect" coords="200,100,300,200" alt="3b" href="http://www.threebottom.com">
      <area shape="rect" coords="300,100,400,200" alt="4b" href="http://www.fourbottom.com">
      <area shape="rect" coords="400,100,500,200" alt="5b" href="http://www.fivebottom.com">
    </map>    
    
    <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    $('area').each(function(){
        var area = $(this),
            alt = area.attr('alt');
        area.mouseenter(function(){
            $('#overlay').html(alt);
        }).mouseleave(function(){
            $('#overlay').html('');
        });
    });
      //]]></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `top` and `left` depending on the `top` and `left` of the coordinates of the map. The following will make the overlay stick to the top of each image, but you can add offsets as needed.

```js
$('area').each(function(){
    var area = $(this),
        alt = area.attr('alt');
    area.mouseenter(function() {
        // Grab the coords, then the top and left
        const coords = area.attr('coords').split(',')
        const top = parseInt(coords[1], 10)
        const left = parseInt(coords[0], 10)
        
        // Use `css()` to modify the top and left of the overlay
        $('#overlay').html(alt).css({
          top: `${top + 40}px`,
          left: `${left}px`,
        })
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $('#overlay').html('');
    });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
    <style id="compiled-css" type="text/css">
    #map {
        position: relative;
    }
    #overlay {
        position: absolute;
        background: #000;
        color: #fff;
        top: 50px;
        left: 50px;
    
        width: 100px;
    
    }
      </style>
    <div id="map">
        <div id="overlay"></div>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/f9HmUmf.jpg" alt="test" usemap="#g1">
    </div>
    
    <map name="g1">
      <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,100,100" alt="one" href="http://www.one.com">
      <area shape="rect" coords="100,0,200,100" alt="two" href="http://www.two.com">
      <area shape="rect" coords="200,0,300,100" alt="three" href="http://www.three.com">
      <area shape="rect" coords="300,0,400,100" alt="4" href="http://www.four.com">
      <area shape="rect" coords="400,0,500,100" alt="5" href="http://www.five.com">
      
      <area shape="rect" coords="0,100,100,200" alt="1b" href="http://www.onebottom.com">
      <area shape="rect" coords="100,100,200,200" alt="2b" href="http://www.twobottom.com">
      <area shape="rect" coords="200,100,300,200" alt="3b" href="http://www.threebottom.com">
      <area shape="rect" coords="300,100,400,200" alt="4b" href="http://www.fourbottom.com">
      <area shape="rect" coords="400,100,500,200" alt="5b" href="http://www.fivebottom.com">
    </map>
```

If you want the overlay to "move" on hover, you can change `css` to `animate` and give it an animate time:

```
$('#overlay').html(alt).animate({
  top: `${top}px`,
  left: `${left}px`,
}, 100)
```

Note that you'll need to change the start position in your CSS to prevent it animating from the centre on the first hover.

Comment: this great thanks. By any chance do you know if its possible to have the overlay move over to the adjacent cells instead?  Strange is when I add say 20  to coords[1] or 0 it moves it over by way more than that.

Comment: How are you adding 20 to the coordinate?

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't convert it. The coordinates are a string, you need to convert to an int before doing arithmetic (see updated answer). I've also updated the answer to show how you can animate the movement.

Comment: yes it was due to string; sorry I'm not versed in javascript. This perfect, thanks a lot.